A way to identify grafts from each other in commercial multi-grafts
When producing multi-grafted fruit trees, is there perhaps an industry standard for identifying which graft is which variety? For example, the relative vertical position of a side or bud graft on the rootstock.
I have not yet found any information about this, but I saw a three-way fruit tree with two grafts seemingly next to each other and the third separate lower. The label followed the pattern of two images and another under. On two-way grafts I bought, it seems they are usually on buds lower and higher - is perhaps one of them the first mentioned in the name? I imagine having an alphabetical or other order of grafts might be a part of quality control in a commercial nursery. Is this so?
Other than waiting for the multi-grafted fruit tree to produce fruit and tell by its differences, is there any convention in grafting multi-grafts by growers?
Edit to clarify: Multi-grafted trees I have seen in shops and nurseries do not have each branch tagged, the label is e.g. "3-Way Apple - Golden Delicious / Granny Smith / Jonathan". I am wondering how to identify the individual varieties on the one multi-graft specimen - e.g. by location on the graft.

No.  (padding here)

Grafting is also localized to what grows well in the area.  Where are you in the world?

@kevinskio, to clarify, I know the grafts I am buying on a particular (usually bare rooted and young) tree, just not which grafted part out of them is which; an example for the area I am in might be "2 way Cherry 'Royal Rainier' - 'Stella'" label, so I am wondering if there is a way of recognizing the grafts (relative location on the rootstock perhaps) before fruiting

You should be able to identify them by looking the fruits. I expect the varieties are very different (else why to do it?). OTOH I recommend you not to use multi variety grafts: it is impossible to keep them balanced. Apple: you should find varieties on weak grafts, and you can plant few of them in a very compact way. -- and I will not start a rant about fruit tree quality on garden centers.
